# Moving Jquery code to script file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery code that is used to auto populate city and state from the zip being entered. However copy and pasting the code to every single view that needs the zip field "jQueryFyed" seems terrible at best but I cannot seem to get it to work unless its specifically in each view. When I drop it in a file and include the script file at the top of the view nothing is hit when i set a break at the very top of the JS.

Here is the current progress:

```
$(function(){
  $('.ZipCode').keyup(function () {
        var zip_in = $(this);

        var zip_box = $('#zipbox');

        if (zip_in.val().length < 5) {
            //  zip_box.removeClass('error success');
        }
        else if (zip_in.val().length > 5) {

        }

        else if ((zip_in.val().length == 5)) {

            // Make HTTP Request
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.zippopotam.us/us/" + zip_in.val(),
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result, success) {
                    // Make the city and state boxes visible
                    places = result['places'][0];


                    if ($('.City').length)         // use this if you are using id to check
                    {
                        $('.City').val(places['place name']);
                    }
                    if ($('.State').length)         // use this if you are using id to check
                    {
                        $(".State").val(convert_state(places['state'], 'abbrev'));
                    }
                    // if (document.get)
                    //zip_box.addClass('success').removeClass('error');
                },
                error: function (result, success) {
                    //zip_box.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
                }
            });
        }
        function convert_state(statename, to) {
            var name = statename.toUpperCase();

            var states = new Array({ 'name': 'Alabama', 'abbrev': 'AL' }, { 'name': 'Alaska', 'abbrev': 'AK' },
                { 'name': 'Arizona', 'abbrev': 'AZ' }, { 'name': 'Arkansas', 'abbrev': 'AR' }, { 'name': 'California', 'abbrev': 'CA' },
                { 'name': 'Colorado', 'abbrev': 'CO' }, { 'name': 'Connecticut', 'abbrev': 'CT' }, { 'name': 'Delaware', 'abbrev': 'DE' },
                { 'name': 'Florida', 'abbrev': 'FL' }, { 'name': 'Georgia', 'abbrev': 'GA' }, { 'name': 'Hawaii', 'abbrev': 'HI' },
                { 'name': 'Idaho', 'abbrev': 'ID' }, { 'name': 'Illinois', 'abbrev': 'IL' }, { 'name': 'Indiana', 'abbrev': 'IN' },
                { 'name': 'Iowa', 'abbrev': 'IA' }, { 'name': 'Kansas', 'abbrev': 'KS' }, { 'name': 'Kentucky', 'abbrev': 'KY' },
                { 'name': 'Louisiana', 'abbrev': 'LA' }, { 'name': 'Maine', 'abbrev': 'ME' }, { 'name': 'Maryland', 'abbrev': 'MD' },
                { 'name': 'Massachusetts', 'abbrev': 'MA' }, { 'name': 'Michigan', 'abbrev': 'MI' }, { 'name': 'Minnesota', 'abbrev': 'MN' },
                { 'name': 'Mississippi', 'abbrev': 'MS' }, { 'name': 'Missouri', 'abbrev': 'MO' }, { 'name': 'Montana', 'abbrev': 'MT' },
                { 'name': 'Nebraska', 'abbrev': 'NE' }, { 'name': 'Nevada', 'abbrev': 'NV' }, { 'name': 'New Hampshire', 'abbrev': 'NH' },
                { 'name': 'New Jersey', 'abbrev': 'NJ' }, { 'name': 'New Mexico', 'abbrev': 'NM' }, { 'name': 'New York', 'abbrev': 'NY' },
                { 'name': 'North Carolina', 'abbrev': 'NC' }, { 'name': 'North Dakota', 'abbrev': 'ND' }, { 'name': 'Ohio', 'abbrev': 'OH' },
                { 'name': 'Oklahoma', 'abbrev': 'OK' }, { 'name': 'Oregon', 'abbrev': 'OR' }, { 'name': 'Pennsylvania', 'abbrev': 'PA' },
                { 'name': 'Rhode Island', 'abbrev': 'RI' }, { 'name': 'South Carolina', 'abbrev': 'SC' }, { 'name': 'South Dakota', 'abbrev': 'SD' },
                { 'name': 'Tennessee', 'abbrev': 'TN' }, { 'name': 'Texas', 'abbrev': 'TX' }, { 'name': 'Utah', 'abbrev': 'UT' },
                { 'name': 'Vermont', 'abbrev': 'VT' }, { 'name': 'Virginia', 'abbrev': 'VA' }, { 'name': 'Washington', 'abbrev': 'WA' },
                { 'name': 'West Virginia', 'abbrev': 'WV' }, { 'name': 'Wisconsin', 'abbrev': 'WI' }, { 'name': 'Wyoming', 'abbrev': 'WY' }
                );
            var returnthis = false;
            $.each(states, function (index, value) {
                if (to == 'name') {
                    if (value.abbrev == name) {
                        returnthis = value.name;
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (to == 'abbrev') {
                    if (value.name.toUpperCase() == name) {
                        returnthis = value.abbrev;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            return returnthis;
        }
    });
});
```

This shows where i load the scripts at in the top of my view.

```
 @modeltype xxxxx_Models.R_X_models.RVM
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/CustomScripts/ZipCodes.js"></script>
```

Making this a reusable has proven to be hard for a new guy such as myself by reusable i mean how do I get this to function simply by dropping it in a separate js file and then when i include it in the view it wires up zip handling automatically using the `ZipCode` `State` `City` classes? that the above code is using??

Comment: You mean something like http://requirejs.org/ ? It's a bit hard to understand what you're looking for... :/

Comment: Did you check browser console for any errors?

Comment: i mean like where I can put the above code in something like ZipCode.js and then include `<script src="~/CustomScripts/ZipCodes.js"></script>` in the view. After doing this inputs with the `ZipCode` class will cause the State and City Fields to automatically be filled.

Comment: @mohamedrias there is no errors in the browser

Comment: did you confirm that the file path is valid for the zipcodes.js file?

Comment: @mohamedrias yes. It should be noted that I added it to the view in VS2012 by dragging it on to the page like I do for all other jquery includes.

Comment: Are you using MVC framework in VS 2012.
 Where is your script placed , Inside head tag or Body ?

Comment: @Kunal Yes its MVC 4 in VS2012. I edited my OP to include the very top of the view where the js files are loaded.

Comment: Can you move this script tag right at the bottom of your view and let me know the results ?. Also, are you using any Shared Layout ?

Comment: @Kunal yes i am using a shared layout. Same results. I think there is possibly another js file conflicting with it.